# Law determining changing of modes of material nature

Tags: gunas

The Bhagavat Gita says:

> 14.10
>
> Sometimes the mode of passion becomes prominent, defeating the mode of
>   goodness, O son of Bharata. And sometimes the mode of goodness defeats
>   passion, and at other times the mode of ignorance defeats goodness and
>   passion. In this way there is always competition for supremacy.

Is there an exact law according to which these modes of material nature change?
If so where are they stated?

Comment: I think there must be a law. Like you said they oscillate. I think it is similar to the Tower of Brahman with cycles and subcycles. but I can't find anything in the scriptures themselves.

Comment: This is like asking "How exactly does Karma work?", "Will I be born as a dog, man or horse or a woman in my next life?" and no one knows for sure :) Check out this video re: [how karma works](https://youtu.be/RUCZeEarVQI). Nothing wrong with your question, but I'm afraid you may never get an answer!